# Spread returned objects from map into one object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, spread

I'm trying to get the results back from my loop to be spread into a variable

```
const updateds = {
    ...
        (Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.updated')).map(item => {
            return {[item.dataset.slug]: item.dataset.position};
        }))
};
```

and the results should be spread to form like so

```
{"chahan": "1", "jacques-lacoste": "2", "testcover": "3", "kreo": "4"}
```

but instead i get

```
{"chahan":"1"},{"jacques-lacoste":"2"},{"testcover":"3"},{"kreo":"4"}
```

Any idea how to achieve so ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `map` higher-order method is always going to return an array. If you want to combine the objects of an array into a single object, the `reduce` higher-order method is what you want to use.

```js
const updateds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.updated')).reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  return {
    ...accumulator,
    [item.dataset.slug]: item.dataset.position
  };
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.reduce

```
const updateds =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.updated')).map(item => {
            return {[item.dataset.slug]: item.dataset.position};
        })
;

const reducedResult=updateds.reduce((obj, Currentitem) =>Object.assign(obj,Currentitem), {})
```